# How to append binary values in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, binary

If I have two variables containing binary values, how do I append them together as one binary value?  For example, if I used WMI to read the registry of two REG_BINARY value, I then want to be able to concatenate the values.

VBScript complains of a type mismatch when you try to join with the '&' operator.

Comment: Clarify what you mean be "binary values".  The first half and the second half of a JPG?  When they are combined, what should you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, I wanted VBScript code for a large userbase as a logon script that has the least chance of failing.  I like the ADO objects, but there are so many mysterious ways ADO can be broken, so I shy away from ADODB.Stream.

Instead, I was able to write conversion code to convert binary to hex encoded strings.  Then, to write back to a `REG_BINARY` value, I convert it to an array of integers and give it to the `SetBinaryValue` WMI method.

Note: `WshShell` can only handle `REG_BINARY` values containing 4 bytes, so it's unusable.

Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

REG_BINARY value will be returned as an array of bytes.  VBScript may reference an array of bytes in a variable and it may pass this array of bytes either as a variant to another function or as a reference to array of bytes.  However VBScript itself can do nothing with the array.

You are going to need some other component to do some from of concatenation:-

```
Function ConcatByteArrays(ra, rb)
    Dim oStream : Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1 'Binary'
    oStream.Write ra
    oStream.Write rb

    oStream.Position = 0

    ConcatByteArrays = oStream.Read(LenB(ra) + LenB(rb))
    oStream.Close

End Function
```

In the above code I'm using the ADODB.Stream object which is ubiquitous on currently supported platforms.

If you actually had multiple arrays that you want to concatenate then you could use the following class:-

```
Class ByteArrayBuilder
    Private moStream

    Sub Class_Initialize()
        Set moStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        moStream.Open
        moStream.Type = 1
    End Sub

    Public Sub Append(rabyt)
        moStream.Write rabyt
    End Sub

    Public Property Get Length
        Length = moStream.Size
    End Property

    Public Function GetArray()
        moStream.Position = 0
        GetArray = moStream.Read(moStream.Size)
    End Function

    Sub Class_Terminate()
        moStream.Close
    End Sub

End Class
```

Call append as many times as you have arrays and retrieve the resulting array with GetArray.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps...

```
result = CStr(val1) & CStr(val2)
```